# Using ASP.net help pages with regular controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've used ASP.net help pages to create a pretty dope API. All of my API controllers are in a sub folder called api under controllers. The routes for the API controllers are:

> api/Admin/{controller}/{id}

and

> api/{placeholder}/{controller}/{id}

I now want to create documentation for my regular MVC controllers (not just api controllers). I've googled around quite a bit and tried adding a route to the controllers in my  routes for the WebApi. That didn't work.

**My Questions:**

1. Is there another tool similar to the ASP.net help pages that can auto generate documentation for regular controllers?
2. Is there a way to expand ASP.net help pages to include support for regular controllers.?

Danke.

Comment: what do you mean by regular controllers? MVC controllers?

Comment: Mvc and Web API are two different frameworks. Help Pages is a Web API feature. So if you want to use help pages you can't just change you MVC controllers to ApiControllers. I don't know of another tool for MVC controllers. Also note that instead of help pages you can try swashbuckle on nuget.org

Comment: I would give swashbuckle a go, but I've already implemented my API docs in help pages. Thanks for the reply though!